# Remember me option of the username and password field same as web browser in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I Need to store or remember me option of  the username and password field value in win forms web browser c# application like any other popular web browser.
For example: in winforms browser it always show without any remembering value.
[Stack Overflow login options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sanGu.png)

But I need to store the username and password value. Like
[Stack Overflow in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqdO8.png)

I'm doing this in this way

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{      
    private readonly string WebPage = "http://example.com";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Navigation_func(WebPage);
    }

    private void Navigation_func(string address)
    {
        //check if the address is blank or null
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
            return;


        //check if the page is blank
        if (address.Equals("about:blank"))
            return;

        //check if the page is start with http or https or file
        if (!address.StartsWith("http://") && !address.StartsWith("https://") && !address.StartsWith("file:/"))
        {
            address = "http://" + address;
        }

        try
        {
            //Actual Navigation
            //webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(address));
            webBrowser1.Navigate(address);
        }
        catch (UriFormatException)
        {
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: So, you are loading a web page in a windows application?

Comment: Yes. I'm loading a web page in win forms web browser application.